# Solver interface needed for MIQP problem Gurobi/MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gurobi

I am somewhat new to Gurobi and I had a question regarding which solver interface to use for solving an MIQP problem using MATLAB and Gurobi as a solver. I have already successfully solved some MILP problems using the intlinprog function in MATLAB (and Gurobi as a solver). However, no such simple function for solving MIQP's exist in MATLAB. Which function or interface should I use and how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic objective and constraints are supported by the Gurobi interface for MATLAB; it is described under [model argument subsection](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/matlab_the_model_argument.html) of the MATLAB API Details section of the Gurobi Optimizer Reference Manual.